# Why the Last "Next" click Show "Blank" for one time and then show the first slide / want to remove Blank Gap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is i have a text slider that's HTML content have structure something Like this:

```
<div id="inner">
    <div class="gallery-slide is-active">
    <div class="slide-content">Question-1 : The color of the sky is...?</div></div>
    <div class="gallery-slide"><div class="slide-content">Question-2 : Paper comes from...?</div></div>
    <div class="gallery-slide"><div class="slide-content">Question-3 : How many hours in a day?</div></div>
    <div class="gallery-slide"><div class="slide-content">Question-4 : A Giraffe is a fish?</div></div>
    </div>
```

If i add HTML manually then the slider work perfectly. means every time when i click `Next` and `Prev` Buttons the slider work correctly to switching next and previous slides.

see this :

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Flexbox Content Slider</title>
  <style>
    .gallery {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 2em 0;
    }

    .gallery-slides {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1280px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .gallery-slide {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      order: 2;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: transform, opacity;
      transition-property: transform, opacity, -webkit-transform;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      transition-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      /* ease-in-out */
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      order: 1;
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active~* {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
      /* E ~ F an F element preceded by an E element
is-active ~ nextSlide element */
    }

    .gallery-selectors {
      width: 5%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 2.5%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .gallery-selector {
      border: 1px solid #343434;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #343434;
      -webkit-transition-property: color;
      transition-property: color;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
      transition-duration: .3s;
    }

    .gallery-selector:hover {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .gallery-selector.is-active {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .slide-img {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }

    .slide-img img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .slide-content {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 1 50%;
      padding-top: 2em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 10%;
    }

    .slide-content h2 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2.2em;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .slide-content p {
      color: #343434;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    /* Background mapColor */
    .background-teal {
      background-color: #54b3a6;
    }

    .background-red {
      background-color: #e72b1e;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      .gallery-slide {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .slide-img {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }

      .slide-content {
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .gallery-selectors {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: row;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .gallery-selector {
        padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
 <section class="gallery background-teal">
    <button data-btn="prev" class="slider-pagination">Pre.❮</button>
    <button data-btn="next" class="slider-pagination">Next ❯</button>
    
    <div class="gallery-slides">
    
    <div id="inner">
    <div class="gallery-slide is-active">
    <div class="slide-content">Question-1 : The color of the sky is...?</div></div>
    <div class="gallery-slide"><div class="slide-content">Question-2 : Paper comes from...?</div></div>
    <div class="gallery-slide"><div class="slide-content">Question-3 : How many hours in a day?</div></div>     <div class="gallery-slide"><div class="slide-content">Question-4 : A Giraffe is a fish?</div></div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
  </section>
  
  
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
  
  
 
  
  
  <script>
    //Javascript Module Pattern
    //app.js
    var total_slides = $('.gallery-slides .gallery-slide').length;
    var remaining_slides = total_slides - 1;
    $(document).on('click', '.slider-pagination', function() {
      var btn = $(this).attr('id');
      var current_slide = $('.is-active');
      if ($(this).attr('data-btn') == 'next') {
        var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) + 1);
        if (next_slide.hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        } else {
          var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - remaining_slides);
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        }

      } else {
        var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - 1);
        if (next_slide.hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        } else {
          var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - remaining_slides);
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        }
      }
    });

    var app = function() {
      var defaults = [];
      return {};
    }();

    $(function() {
      // new app.gallery();
      $('.gallery').each(function() {
        //$(this).data(new app.gallery(this));
      });
    });

    //myModule
    app.gallery = function($, _, app) {
      var def = function(el, opts) {
        this.$els = {
          'el': $(el)
        };

        this.options = _.extend({
          link: 'data-link'
        }, opts);
        console.log(this.options.link);
        this.controller = this.$els.el.find('.slider-div');
        // this.$gallery = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slides');
        // this.$slide = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slide');

        this.states = {
          'active': 'is-active'
        };
        init.call(this);
      };

      var init = function() {
        this.bind();
      };

      def.prototype = {
        bind: function() {
          console.log('gallery loaded');
          var self = this;
          this.setActive(1);
          this.controller.on('click', _.bind(this.slideNext, this));
        },

        slideNext: function(ev) {
          var i = $(ev.currentTarget).attr(this.options.link);
          this.setActive(i);
        },

        setActive: function(index) {
          var self = this;
          this.currentActive = index;

          this.controller.removeClass(this.states.active).filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr(self.options.link) == index;
          }).addClass(self.states.active);
        }
      };
      return def;
    }

    (jQuery, _, app);
  </script>
  
  
  
  
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

But Now, Here i added a text box that is doing the task of adding content to slider from text box means when i add these lines through text box, the `Next` and `Prev` button work correctly, **But But** at the last Question means after Number 4 question when we click on `Next` button there is one time show **Blank Space**, and then it takes to first slide/Question, Why? Here i want to remove the **Blank Space** after four number question.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Flexbox Content Slider</title>
  <style>
    .gallery {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 2em 0;
    }

    .gallery-slides {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1280px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .gallery-slide {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      order: 2;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: transform, opacity;
      transition-property: transform, opacity, -webkit-transform;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      transition-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      /* ease-in-out */
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      order: 1;
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active~* {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
      /* E ~ F an F element preceded by an E element
is-active ~ nextSlide element */
    }

    .gallery-selectors {
      width: 5%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 2.5%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .gallery-selector {
      border: 1px solid #343434;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #343434;
      -webkit-transition-property: color;
      transition-property: color;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
      transition-duration: .3s;
    }

    .gallery-selector:hover {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .gallery-selector.is-active {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .slide-img {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }

    .slide-img img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .slide-content {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 1 50%;
      padding-top: 2em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 10%;
    }

    .slide-content h2 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2.2em;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .slide-content p {
      color: #343434;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    /* Background mapColor */
    .background-teal {
      background-color: #54b3a6;
    }

    .background-red {
      background-color: #e72b1e;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      .gallery-slide {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .slide-img {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }

      .slide-content {
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .gallery-selectors {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: row;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .gallery-selector {
        padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>



<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>

<button class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">add text</button>



<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
 <section class="gallery background-teal">
    <button data-btn="prev" class="slider-pagination">Pre.❮</button>
    <button data-btn="next" class="slider-pagination">Next ❯</button>
    
    <div class="gallery-slides">
    
     <div id="inner"> </div>
      
    </div>
  </section>
  
  
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
  
  
  
  <script>
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
const textArea = document.getElementById('input');
const innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var message = textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // split the textarea entries into an array
  let lines = (textArea.value).split("\n");

// iterate over each line, creating a div/span and inserting into the DOM
  lines.forEach( (line, index) => {
    let encodedLine = encodeHtmlEntity(line);

    let classList = 'gallery-slide';
    if (index === 0) {
      classList += ' is-active'
    }

    let newElement = `<div class="${classList}"><div class="slide-content">${encodedLine}</div></div>`;
    
    innerDiv.innerHTML += newElement;
  });
  
  // reset the textarea
  textArea.value = '';

});

function encodeHtmlEntity(input) {
  var output = input.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
  });

  return output;
}

$('.quiz').eq(0).addClass('classYouNeedToAdd');
</script>

  
  
  
  
  
  <script>
    //Javascript Module Pattern
    //app.js
    var total_slides = $('.gallery-slides .gallery-slide').length;
    var remaining_slides = total_slides - 1;
    $(document).on('click', '.slider-pagination', function() {
      var btn = $(this).attr('id');
      var current_slide = $('.is-active');
      if ($(this).attr('data-btn') == 'next') {
        var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) + 1);
        if (next_slide.hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        } else {
          var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - remaining_slides);
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        }

      } else {
        var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - 1);
        if (next_slide.hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        } else {
          var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - remaining_slides);
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        }
      }
    });

    var app = function() {
      var defaults = [];
      return {};
    }();

    $(function() {
      // new app.gallery();
      $('.gallery').each(function() {
        //$(this).data(new app.gallery(this));
      });
    });

    //myModule
    app.gallery = function($, _, app) {
      var def = function(el, opts) {
        this.$els = {
          'el': $(el)
        };

        this.options = _.extend({
          link: 'data-link'
        }, opts);
        console.log(this.options.link);
        this.controller = this.$els.el.find('.slider-div');
 this.$gallery = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slides');
 this.$slide = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slide');

        this.states = {
          'active': 'is-active'
        };
        init.call(this);
      };

      var init = function() {
        this.bind();
      };

      def.prototype = {
        bind: function() {
          console.log('gallery loaded');
          var self = this;
          this.setActive(1);
          this.controller.on('click', _.bind(this.slideNext, this));
        },

        slideNext: function(ev) {
          var i = $(ev.currentTarget).attr(this.options.link);
          this.setActive(i);
        },

        setActive: function(index) {
          var self = this;
          this.currentActive = index;

          this.controller.removeClass(this.states.active).filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr(self.options.link) == index;
          }).addClass(self.states.active);
        }
      };
      return def;
    }

    (jQuery, _, app);
    
  </script>
  
  
  
  
  
  
</body>

</html>
```

> You can try these four questions Copy/Pasting in this text box and then press `add text` Button. Then see

```
Question-1 : The color of the sky is...?
Question-2 : Paper comes from...?
Question-3 : How many hours in a day?
Question-4 : A Giraffe is a fish?
```

Anybody Expert form stackoverflow community can solve this issue. What's the problem am making here.

By the way , Thanks in Advance and Love You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Flexbox Content Slider</title>
  <style>
    .gallery {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 2em 0;
    }

    .gallery-slides {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1280px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .gallery-slide {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      order: 2;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: transform, opacity;
      transition-property: transform, opacity, -webkit-transform;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      transition-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      /* ease-in-out */
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      order: 1;
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active~* {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
      /* E ~ F an F element preceded by an E element
is-active ~ nextSlide element */
    }

    .gallery-selectors {
      width: 5%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 2.5%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .gallery-selector {
      border: 1px solid #343434;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #343434;
      -webkit-transition-property: color;
      transition-property: color;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
      transition-duration: .3s;
    }

    .gallery-selector:hover {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .gallery-selector.is-active {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .slide-img {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }

    .slide-img img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .slide-content {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 1 50%;
      padding-top: 2em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 10%;
    }

    .slide-content h2 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2.2em;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .slide-content p {
      color: #343434;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    /* Background mapColor */
    .background-teal {
      background-color: #54b3a6;
    }

    .background-red {
      background-color: #e72b1e;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      .gallery-slide {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .slide-img {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }

      .slide-content {
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .gallery-selectors {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: row;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .gallery-selector {
        padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>



<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>

<button class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">add text</button>



<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <section class="gallery background-teal">
    <button data-btn="prev" class="slider-pagination">Pre.❮</button>
    <button data-btn="next" class="slider-pagination">Next ❯</button>

    <div class="gallery-slides">

      <div id="inner"> </div>

    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>



  <script>
    const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
    const textArea = document.getElementById('input');
    const innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
    var message = textArea.value;

    sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // split the textarea entries into an array
      let lines = (textArea.value).split("\n");

      // iterate over each line, creating a div/span and inserting into the DOM
      lines.forEach((line, index) => {
        let encodedLine = encodeHtmlEntity(line);

        let classList = 'gallery-slide';
        if (index === 0) {
          classList += ' is-active'
        }

        let newElement = `<div class="${classList}"><div class="slide-content">${encodedLine}</div></div>`;

        innerDiv.innerHTML += newElement;
      });

      // reset the textarea
      textArea.value = '';

    });

    function encodeHtmlEntity(input) {
      var output = input.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
        return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
      });

      return output;
    }

    $('.quiz').eq(0).addClass('classYouNeedToAdd');
  </script>






  <script>
    //Javascript Module Pattern
    //app.js

    $(document).on('click', '.slider-pagination', function() {
      var total_slides = $('.gallery-slides .gallery-slide').length;
      var remaining_slides = total_slides - 1;
      var btn = $(this).attr('id');
      var current_slide = $('.is-active');
      if ($(this).attr('data-btn') == 'next') {
        var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) + 1);
        if (next_slide.hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        } else {
          var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - remaining_slides);
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        }

      } else {
        var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - 1);
        if (next_slide.hasClass('gallery-slide')) {
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        } else {
          var next_slide = $(".gallery-slide").eq($(".gallery-slide").index($(current_slide)) - remaining_slides);
          current_slide.removeClass('is-active');
          next_slide.addClass('is-active');
        }
      }
    });

    var app = function() {
      var defaults = [];
      return {};
    }();

    $(function() {
      // new app.gallery();
      $('.gallery').each(function() {
        //$(this).data(new app.gallery(this));
      });
    });

    //myModule
    app.gallery = function($, _, app) {
      var def = function(el, opts) {
        this.$els = {
          'el': $(el)
        };

        this.options = _.extend({
          link: 'data-link'
        }, opts);
        console.log(this.options.link);
        this.controller = this.$els.el.find('.slider-div');
        this.$gallery = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slides');
        this.$slide = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slide');

        this.states = {
          'active': 'is-active'
        };
        init.call(this);
      };

      var init = function() {
        this.bind();
      };

      def.prototype = {
        bind: function() {
          console.log('gallery loaded');
          var self = this;
          this.setActive(1);
          this.controller.on('click', _.bind(this.slideNext, this));
        },

        slideNext: function(ev) {
          var i = $(ev.currentTarget).attr(this.options.link);
          this.setActive(i);
        },

        setActive: function(index) {
          var self = this;
          this.currentActive = index;

          this.controller.removeClass(this.states.active).filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr(self.options.link) == index;
          }).addClass(self.states.active);
        }
      };
      return def;
    }

    (jQuery, _, app);
  </script>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow ! It's Looks Like Magic !

many many thanks again for helping me again. Love You @Nitin

Comment: Can i know in which line of code am making mistake ?

Comment: I just placed the length of slider code after the click statement. near line# 264 & 265

Comment: oh okay You are Great Guy Thanks and Love from India / Rajasthan, Can i know where are you from ?

Comment: @RRSuthar I have just sent the email to you